# Are the abstracts in in enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz corrupted?

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikimedia-dumps

I've been looking at the wikimedia abstracts dump file (enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz) for the last week and noticed that the abstracts for many items appear to be corrupted.

For example, the wikipedia page for [Alabama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama) contains the following dumped abstract:

```
<title>Wikipedia: Alabama</title>
<url>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama</url>
<abstract>(We dare defend our rights)</abstract>
```

Similarly, the abstract for the [Abraham Lincoln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln) item is:

```
<title>Wikipedia: Abraham Lincoln</title>
<url>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln</url>
<abstract>| term_start1 = March 4, 1847</abstract>
```

Which appears to be a partial snippet from the infobox.

This kind of corruption seems to be present for a majority of items in the the enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz.

I'd appreciate any advice anyone has  on whether this is a bug or whether I have a misunderstanding about this dump file.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you compared it with previous dump files?

Comment: @Tgr yeah, sorry, I should've mentioned. All the dumps from the last week appear the same. Perhaps I should go back further and see if this is a problem that appeared a some point.

Comment: Seems like this [has been a problem](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:U95l97ku4fd46it4) for a long time.

Comment: [Event longer than that.](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T111775)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably just the [extraction code](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-ActiveAbstract/blob/941607cb3a004cf51131099156b646a289508eb3/includes/AbstractFilter.php#L214) behaving badly; it's not very sophisticated.

FWIW Wikipedia has two different extract/summary APIs, which both seem behave reasonably here (the older, api.php-based one is a bit broken but not completely broken):

> https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&prop=extracts&titles=Alabama%7CAbraham%20Lincoln&exsentences=1&exintro=1&explaintext=1
>
> Alabama () is a state in the southeastern region of the United States.
>
> Abraham Lincoln (; February 12, 1809 \u2013 April 15, 1865) was an American statesman and lawyer who served as the 16th president of the United States (1861\u20131865).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Alabama
>
> Alabama is a state in the southeastern region of the United States. It is bordered by Tennessee to the north, Georgia to the east, Florida and the Gulf of Mexico to the south, and Mississippi to the west. Alabama is the 30th largest by area and the 24th-most populous of the U.S. states. With a total of 1,500 miles (2,400 km) of inland waterways, Alabama has among the most of any state.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Abraham_Lincoln
>
> Abraham Lincoln was an American statesman and lawyer who served as the 16th president of the United States (1861–1865). Lincoln led the nation through its greatest moral, constitutional, and political crisis in the American Civil War. He preserved the Union, abolished slavery, strengthened the federal government, and modernized the U.S. economy.

Neither of those have dumps though.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr, that's really helpful to know that the problem is likely with the extraction process. Given the amount of data I'm processing, I'm limited to using the dumps. Do you know whether there's any likelihood that one of the API extraction methods might ever be applied to the dumps to fix this?

Comment: Ever is a long time, but I don't think there's any interest in it for now. The abstracts dumps are a legacy of a collaboration with Yahoo; I'm not sure anyone really uses them these days.

Comment: Depending on what you want, you could try using Wikidata descriptions (they are much shorter though). You can get the wikidata identifier from the `page_props` dump, and the description from wikidata's `wbt_text` dump.

Comment: thanks heaps for that. I'll give the Wikidata descriptions a go.